# Unable to find wget working directory

Tags: command-line, wget

hello im trying to find wget working directory and when i use this command

```
wget -P
```

or

```
Wget --directory-prefix
```

and i get this as an answer:

Wget: option requires an argument -- 'P'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: `wget` doesn't have a "working directory", it uses the directory of the parent process (`pwd`). Read `man wget`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run wget in a specific directory you can do a thing similar to this:

```
$ clear
$ echo "1 $(pwd)"; ls; (cd /tmp; echo "2 $(pwd)"; ls; sleep 1) ; echo "3 $(pwd)"; ls
1 /home/hannu
...
list of local files 
...
2 /tmp
...
list of files in /tmp 
...
GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on linux-gnu.
3 /home/hannu
...
list of local files again 
...
```

Note that the commands inside the `(`  `)`  will have the current work directory (printed by `pwd`) set to `/tmp` in my example.
The commands inside the parenthesis get executed "in a subshell".

To get to grips with how the Terminal (bash) works, what can be done and how you can do it; I recommend at least browsing through the "Bash guides" at [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org)